# How to download particular field when export Mysql data to Excel Download?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, excel

If I want to change field name @ the time of excel download to submit user,
   how to do that? how to download particular column in the selected table?

```
 <?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "username"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "password";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "databasename";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "tablename"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

I am using Above mentioned Code to export Mysql data to Excel Download.
   for ex, in my table i have the fields of id, name, status, create_date.
   but @ the time of export mysql data to excel download i wants to takes the
   filed of name & status only. help me to solve this prob. thanks for
   advance.

Comment: `YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE` ... are you telling us to ignore the code below that line?

Comment: No, actually i am using mentioned above code. but i don't want to download all the fileds in my table. how to do that?

Comment: for ex, in my table i have the fields of id, name, status, create_date. but @ the time of export mysql data to excel download i wants to takes the filed of name & status only. help me to solve this prob. thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just be looking for a query which selects only the columns you want, something like this:

```
$sql = "Select name as organization, status from $DB_TBLName";
```

instead of the following, which selects all columns:

```
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
```

Note that I used an *alias* to change the name of the `name` column to `organization`.

Comment: let me know that how to change field name, In My table i have the field name of Name, but i wants to change the field name, "Organization" instead of "Name"

Comment: thanks a lot. one more final ques, If i maintain my table as id, cat_id, name.but cat_id, i maintain like as a foreign key (i taken by another table) like this method, The another table, i maintain cat_id, description. now in my excel download i need to retrive cat description instead of cat_id.how to change sql code.

Comment: @Ived It sounds like you just need a join between the two tables, but maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: Yap. I am going to raise a quest, How to Join/Combine two table when export Mysql data to Excel Download? after 90 min only I can able to raise new ques. thanks a lot

Comment: When you ask the new question be sure to give table structure, otherwise it could be difficult to answer.

Comment: hi, plz help me to solve,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474942/how-to-join-combine-two-table-when-export-mysql-data-to-excel-download