# How to Join/Combine two table when export Mysql data to Excel Download?

Tags: html, mysql, excel

I Maintain 4 tables.

Table 1(table name: products)-> pro_id, pro_model, price

Table 2(table name: pro_description)-> id, pro_id, pro_name, pro_desp

Table 3(table name: pro_to_category)-> id, pro_id, cat_id

Table 4(table name: category)-> cat_id, cat_desp

Now I wants to download the fields, when I export mysql data to excel 
   download, pro_id, pro_name, pro_desp, price, pro_model, category
   (notes: category needs the cat_desp, no need cat_id)
    Thanks for advance. help me to solve. :(

```
    <?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "username"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "password";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "databasename";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "tablename"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "excelfilename";         //File Name
/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
//create MySQL connection   
$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName";
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a query along these lines:

```
SELECT
    t1.pro_id,
    t2.pro_name,
    t2.pro_desp,
    t1.price,
    t1.pro_model,
    t4.cat_desp
FROM products t1
INNER JOIN pro_description t2
    ON t1.pro_id = t2.pro_id
INNER JOIN pro_to_category t3
    ON t1.pro_id = t3.pro_id
INNER JOIN category t4
    ON t3.cat_id = t4.cat_id
```

Comment: :) thank u sooo very much working fine. sorry one more doubt. In that table 1 (products), I maintained create_date (int). 
normally we are using int to date (date('d-m-Y',$str))
how to convert date format (int to date) when we export data form sql to excel?

Comment: I'm not sure about this.  Ideally, a date column in MySQL should be exportable as a date.  If you want to force into a string, look into using [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: ok. thanks for your help. i'll try to get solution for date. if i get o/p i'll update soon.

Comment: let me know how to use GROUP BY products .pro_id. I tried but its not working. help me to solve

Comment: @Ived You should ask a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148611/group-by-using-join-combine-two-table-when-export-mysql-data-to-excel-download